# Unable to obtain the connection string for an Azure Postgres database server using the CLI

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I have an Azure database server which I need to obtain the connection string for by way of command line.  However, it is telling me that the "az postgres server show-connection-string" is not right, that "show-connection-string" is not recognized.  I did a copy and paste from the Microsoft documentation but it gives the error, and I can't seem to find the answer.  I could use a hand obtaining the connection string.  Here is my CLI command:

```
az postgres server show-connection-string --server-name myserver1 --admin-user myuser@myserver --admin-password mypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are running the latest version of the Azure CLI.  As of this answer, the latest is **2.26.0** but I got this command to run in [CloudShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/cloud-shell) which is running **2.25.0**.

```
ken@Azure:~$ az postgres server show-connection-string --server-name myserver1 --admin-user myuser@myserver --admin-password mypassword
{
  "connectionStrings": {
    "C++ (libpq)": "host=myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname={database} user=myuser@myserver@myserver1 password=mypassword sslmode=require",
    "ado.net": "Server=myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com;Database={database};Port=5432;User Id=myuser@myserver@myserver1;Password=mypassword;",
    "jdbc": "jdbc:postgresql://myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/{database}?user=myuser@myserver@myserver1&password=mypassword",
    "node.js": "var client = new pg.Client('postgres://myuser@myserver@myserver1:mypassword@myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/{database}');",
    "php": "host=myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname={database} user=myuser@myserver@myserver1 password=mypassword",
    "psql_cmd": "postgresql://myuser@myserver@myserver1:mypassword@myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com/{database}?sslmode=require",
    "python": "cnx = psycopg2.connect(database='{database}', user='myuser@myserver@myserver1', host='myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com', password='mypassword', port='5432')",
    "ruby": "cnx = PG::Connection.new(:host => 'myserver1.postgres.database.azure.com', :user => 'myuser@myserver@myserver1', :dbname => '{database}', :port => '5432', :password => 'mypassword')"
  }
}
```